# How can I use a class from a project without including the project in my solution?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, dependencies, projects-and-solutions

I have a web solution that looks like this:

```
Domain (solution folder)

    Artemis.Core (project in solution)
        Interfaces (project folder)
            IRepository.cs
        Address.cs
        ...
        User.cs

    Artemis.Data (project in solution)
        Repository.cs

Artemis.User (project in solution)
    IUserOrderTask.cs
    IUserProfileTask.cs
      ...

Artemis.Tasks.User (project in solution)
    UserOrderTask.cs
    UserProfileTask.cs
    ...

Artemis.WebSite (project in solution)
   Controllers (project folder)
   Models (project folder)
   Views (project folder)
   ...
```

There's a lot of other projects and files in this solution. It's a complex web of dependencies that I've been asked to reduce. Here are the dependencies of each project, ordered by amount:

Artemis.WebSite depends on:

- Artemis.Core
- Artemis.Data
- Artemis.User
- Artemis.Tasks.User

Artemis.Tasks.User depends on:

- Artemis.Core
- Artemis.User

Artemis.User and Artemis.Data depend on:

- Artemis.Core

Finally Artemis.Core depends on nothing.

My task is to remove everything from the solution that Artemis.WebSite doesn't *explicitly* depend on. Most of these projects are used in several solutions for other web sites, so removing all the stuff from Artemis.Core except User.cs (for instance) is not an option.

How can I do this without modifying the projects?

Comment: want a simple answer? you can't if you aren't going to remove/duplicate code. There's no way to remove dependencies. Only way to do, but is really dirty, create just one project, add all code to it, and now you only have one dependecy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add specific CS files as links to projects, which would bring in a class without touching the original project, or copy the file.

1. Right-click target project
2. Select Add Existing Item...
3. Select CS file you want to "add".
4. DO NOT CLICK ADD
5. Click **drop down arrow** next to Add and select *Add as Link*.

Comment: Is there any downside to using linked files this way?

Comment: Not as long as all your developers understand what linked files are (so they don't change them and break some other project without knowing it).  As far as your project goes, it doesn't care if its a local file or a linked file. It compiles exactly the same way.

Comment: Well this is weird. I added User.cs as a linked file to Artemis.User, but not to Artemis.Tasks.User (which also references it). I thought I would have to add it as a linked file to both but apparently not.